# How to make block move to left when resizing screen?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have div block with the text that is overlapping image, when i'm resizing screen, the block with the text getting smaller but staying at the same position. What i want to achieve is to move block to the left side when resizing screen so the whole block can fit into the screen.

How can i do it properly?
Here is my current code..

```css
.our-project-section {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.zundas-project img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 50%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.projects-wrapper {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.project-description {
  padding: 25px;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -30%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.project-description p {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.project-description h3 {
  position: relative;
}

.project-description h3::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  top: 32px;
  left: -85px;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.project-description a {
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="our-project-section">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">

      <div class="projects-wrapper">

        <div class="zundas-project">

          <img src="https://static.dezeen.com/uploads/2018/02/riverfront-square-michael-green-lotus-newark-new-jersey-usa-largest-timber-office-building_dezeen_2364_col_1-852x537.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="project-description">
            <h3>Project Name</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga id molestias enim molestiae, corporis at ad ipsum perferendis commodi dicta dolorem ea eos magnam reprehenderit quae temporibus. Animi quasi labore fugit reiciendis odit officiis
              reprehenderit saepe earum.</p>
            <a href="#">More Information</a>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</section>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kani339/kp6L28rz/2/)

Comment: You have some classes as "pull-right", "pull-left". For more reference, https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_helpers.asp

Comment: use media query to define position based on the window width/resolution

Comment: you want the text to be inside the image right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`media-query`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 758px) {
  .project-description {
       right: 0;
    left: -19px;
  }
}
```

See fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/kp6L28rz/11/

```css
.our-project-section {
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.zundas-project img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 50%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;

}

.projects-wrapper {
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.project-description {
    padding: 25px;
    width: 50%;
    /* width: 400px; */
    height: auto;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    /* right: -80px; */
    right: -30%;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;

}

.project-description p {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.project-description h3 {
    position: relative;
}

.project-description h3::after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:80px;
    height:3px;
    background:#fff;
    top:32px;
    left:-85px;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
}

.project-description a {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 800;
    position: relative;
    top:20px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 758px) {
  .project-description {
       right: 0;
    left: -19px;
  }
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <div class="container">
            <section class="our-project-section">

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">

                        <div class="projects-wrapper">

                            <div class="zundas-project">

                                <img src="https://static.dezeen.com/uploads/2018/02/riverfront-square-michael-green-lotus-newark-new-jersey-usa-largest-timber-office-building_dezeen_2364_col_1-852x537.jpg" alt="">
                                <div class="project-description">
                                    <h3>Project Name</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga id molestias enim molestiae, corporis at ad ipsum perferendis commodi dicta dolorem ea eos magnam reprehenderit quae temporibus. Animi quasi labore fugit reiciendis odit officiis reprehenderit saepe earum.</p>
                                    <a href="#">More Information</a>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </section>

        </div>
```

Comment: tell for more help!